# Cyclotomic euclidean number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I´m here because I want to repeat my question about the norm-euclidean algorithm in a particluar cyclotomic integer ring.

Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{32})$ and $A=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{32}]$. On the page 28 of "Cyclotomic euclidean number fields", Reza Akhtar wrote a proof attributed to Hendrik Lenstra Jr. in which he showed that $A$ is not euclidean. However, I do not fully understand this proof.  In the document you can see the following proof:

"We claim in particular, that there are not elements $q, r$ in $A$ such that

$1+(1+\zeta)^5=q(1+6)^6+r$  with $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(r)<N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}((1+\zeta)^6)$

Using Proposition A.5 (1), we compute $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}((1+\zeta)=2$, so

$$N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}((1+\zeta)^6)=64$$

Lemma 7.1: Every element in $A$ which is prime to $1+\zeta$ has norm equivalent with $1$ mod $32$

Proof: ( I do understand this proof, so I will omit).

So if we can find $q,r$ sush that 
$1+(1+\zeta)^5=q(1+6)^6+r$  with $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(r)<64$, Lemma 7.1 and Proposition A.5(6) and (9) tell us that $r$ is either a unit or a product of prime powers, each equivalent to $1$ mod $32$. The conditions forces $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(r)=1$. It is known that the unit group of $A$ is generated by $(1-\zeta^{i})/(1-\zeta)$, where $i$ is in ${1,2,3....,8}$

We examine the residues of each of these elements in the multiplicative group $M$ of the ring $A/(1+\zeta)^6$

Since          $(2)=((1+\zeta)^{16}$
as ideals, we observe that

$A/(1+\zeta)^6$=Z/$2$Z[$\zeta$]/$(1+\zeta)^6$

therby greatly simplifying computation. Finally, it can be shown (by a direct computation)
that the subgroup $M$ generated by the residues of this units has order $16$ and hence does not contain the residue of $1+(1+\zeta)^5$, giving a contradiction."

My first two questions are:

1) Why is $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(r)=1$?

2) Why the unit group of $A$ is generated by $(1-\zeta^{i})/(1-\zeta)$, where $i$ is in ${1,2,3....,8}$?

Best regards, José

Comment: Couldn't you at least post a link to this document that **the entire question is based on**? And what if this document one day is taken off the web? The best solution is to explain, in as much detail as possible, the actual content you want to ask about. If you do not want to type it out, then at least post screenshots/scans of the relevant pages.

Comment: I'm sorry @Zev Chonoles. I edited my question as you want.

Comment: Now I understand why r is a unit.

Comment: But....what about the unit group of A?

Comment: So where is the contradiction? Why the subgroup of M generated by the residues of the units of A has order 16? Why does not contain the residue of 1+(1+\zeta)^5

Answer (score 2):

Let $A = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{32}]$ be the ring of integers of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{32})$.  Jose is referring to Reza Akhtar's senior thesis, [Cyclotomic Euclidean Number Fields](http://calico.mth.muohio.edu/reza/research/final/seniorthesis.pdf), where he gives Lenstra's proof that $A$ is not a Euclidean number field.

Jose asks why Akhtar states that the unit group of $A$ is generated by
$$\frac{1-\zeta^i}{1-\zeta}$$
with $1 \leq i \leq 8$.

The above units are known as "cyclotomic units," and it would be more precise to state that the unit group of $A$ is generated by those cyclotomic units *and* the root of unity $\zeta$.

Generally, given a cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ where $n$ is a prime power, e.g. 32, the group $C$ of cyclotomic units, is generated by $\zeta$ and units of the form $(1-\zeta^i)/(1-\zeta)$, is always a finite index subgroup of the full unit group $E$.  Moreover, we have the remarkable fact that
$$h^+ = [E:C],$$
where $h^+$ is the class number of the maximal real subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})$.

In the case of $n=32$, we have that the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{32} + \zeta_{32}^{-1})$ is 1 (in fact, J.P. Cerri proved that it is norm-Eulicdean!).  Thus, $C=E$.

**Added later in response to Jose's inquiry:**
Perhaps it's best just to do the actual calculation:

Let $X=1-\zeta$. Then we are working over the quotient ring $R = \mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^6)$.  In $R$, the invertible elements are the elements with nonzero constant term.

The root of unity $\zeta$ corresponds to invertible element $1+X$ in $R$, the cyclotomic unit $1+\zeta+\zeta^2$ corresponds to the invertible element $1+X+X^2$ in $R$, and cyclotomic unit $1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^4$ corresponds to the invertible element $1+X^3+X^4$ in $R$.  The other two cyclotomic units, $1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3$ and $1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^4+\zeta^5$ correspond to elements that are not invertible in $R$, so we can ignore them.

Now consider the subring $M$ of the multiplicative group $R^\times$ of $R$ that is generated by $1+X$, $1+X+X^2$ and $1+X^3+X^4$.  The element $1+(1+\zeta)^5$ corresponds to $1+X^5 \in R^\times$.

To show: $1+X^5 \notin M$.

By brute force calculation, it turns out that $M$ is order 16 (vs $R^\times$ which is order 32), and the elements of $M$ are:
$$\{1, 1+X, 1+X^2, 1+X^3, 1+X^4, 1+X+X^2, 1+X^2+X^4, 1+X^3+X^4, 1+X+X^2+X^3, 1+X+X^3+X^4, 1+X+X^3+X^5, 1+X+X^4+X^5, 1+X^2+X^3+X^5, 1+X+X^2+X^4+X^5, 1+X^2+X^3+X^4+X^5, 1+X+X^2+X^3+X^4+X^5 \}.$$
By inspection, $1+X^5 \notin M$, and we are done.

Comment: Do you understand why the subgroup of M generated by the residues of the units of A does not contain the residue of 1+(1+\zeta)^5?

Comment: @JoseCamarillo - let me add something about this

Comment: @JoseCamarillo - Hi.  Are you still working on euclidean fields or related areas?  Are you at a university?

Comment: Thank you again. Just a few days ago, I had been working again on cyclotomic fields euclidean for the $N_{L,\mathbb{Q}}$-map. I want to find a solution for the still open cases: you konow n=17,19.... I'm working as an Assistant Teacher in Venezuela. Today, I'm reading Kummer's proof for n=5 and Masley's proof for the case n=12. What about you?

Comment: @JoseCamarillo - If you ever wish to reach me directly you can get my email address from here: http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~jmill268/

Comment: Thank you so much. I will write to you.